# How to identify the issue when Java OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

How to identify the issue when java `OutOfMemoryError` or `stackoverflow` comes in production. By which reason it is coming or why the server is down.

For example I am developing an application which is lived on production and UAT. Instantly on production java `OutOfMemoryError` or `stackoverflow`.

Then how can we track this issue, by which reason it has happened ? Is there any technique that can tell me by which code flow this is happening ?

Please explain it. I have faced this issue many times.

Comment: First look at the stacktrace if you call a method recursivly.

Comment: Follow the stack traces. If nothing found attach a profiler in your test environment and run some load testing.

Comment: Stack traces can be misleading, since it is likely that not the offender (the process, that consumed the most memory) will throw an exception

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an OutOfMemoryError and how do I debug and fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510188/what-is-an-outofmemoryerror-and-how-do-i-debug-and-fix-it)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you face it in production and you cannot really reason about it from stacktraces or logs, you need to analyze what was in there.

Get the VM to dump on OOM

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
-XX:HeapDumpPath="/tmp"
```

And use that for analysis. The memory analyzer tool (http://eclipse.org/mat/) is a good standalone program for this analysis.

Comment: have you heard any tracker for which i can analyse which release has send to production.any thread tracker.

Comment: not sure I understand. Do your application not assemble a version number inside the jar files? And do they not print it on console when started?

Comment: Note that the `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` flag must be prefixed by `-XX:+` and not `-XX:-` (some documentation gets it wrong). I'm editing your answer to fix this.

Comment: @ntoskrnl E.g. this page makes it look like it works with a minus instead of a plus: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html

Comment: That page isn't wrong, @Eli. The table column heading includes **default value** to indicate to the reader that the heap dump option is disabled by default. The emphasis could be made a lot clearer though.

Answer (score 6):

The [Oracle docs:- Troubleshooting Memory Leaks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-VM/html/memleaks.html) has detailed explanation on it:

> This error is thrown when there is insufficient space to allocate an
> object in the Java heap or in a particular area of the heap. The
> garbage collector cannot make any further space available to
> accommodate a new object, and the heap cannot be expanded further.
>
> .....
>
> An early step to diagnose an OutOfMemoryError is to determine what the
> error means. Does it mean that the Java heap is full, or does it mean
> that the native heap is full? To help you answer this question, the
> following subsections explain some of the possible error messages,
> with reference to the detail part of the message:
>
> Exception in thread "main": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap
> space
>
> See 3.1.1 Detail Message: Java heap space.
>
> Exception in thread "main": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
>
> See 3.1.2 Detail Message: PermGen space.
>
> Exception in thread "main": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested
> array size exceeds VM limit
>
> See 3.1.3 Detail Message: Requested array size exceeds VM limit.
>
> Exception in thread "main": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: request 
> bytes for . Out of swap space?
>
> See 3.1.4 Detail Message: request  bytes for . Out of
> swap space?.
>
> Exception in thread "main": java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: 
>  (Native method)
>
> See 3.1.5 Detail Message:   (Native method).

**UPDATE:-**

You can [download](http://openjdk.java.net/groups/hotspot/) the HotSpot VM source code from OpenJDK. If you want to monitor and track the memory footprint of your Java Heap spaces ie, the young generation and old generation spaces is to enable verbose GC from your HotSpot VM. You may add the following parameters within your JVM start-up arguments:

```
-verbose:gc –XX:+PrintGCDetails –XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps –Xloggc:<app path>/gc.log
```

Comment: You are defining what error means, which is not the question.

Comment: @JunedAhsan:- `has detailed explanation on it`

Comment: if issue come on production that is on other country and I am in india. I need solve issue instantly.On production side any server log will generated to track the issue or any logger which is the source that can give me tracking issue.(because code has been done my side and after sending to production i need only solution )

Answer (score 2):

You can use **`jvisualvm`** to manage your process at the runtime.

You can see memory, heap space, objects etc ...

This program is located in your `bin` directory of your `JDK`.

Comment: If you are using Oracle JDK... But jvisualvm can connect to other JDK's processes as well, example with WebSphere described here: http://jcraane.blogspot.de/2012/01/monitoring-ibm-jvm-with-visualvm.html But the most interesting in that case, the Memory sampling (how much which objects are allocated) is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to try to reproduce the problem in place where you are free to debug it - on dev server or on your local machine. Then try to debug, look for recursive invocations, heap size and what objects are being created. Unfortunately it's not always easy to reproduce prod env (with it's load and so on) on local machine, therefore finding the root cause of such error might be a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of memory given to Java process is specified at startup. memory  divided into separate areas, heap and permgen being the most familiar sub-areas.

While you specify the maximum size of the heap allowed for this particular process via -Xmx,
the corresponding parameter for permgen is -XX:MaxPermSize. 90% of the Java apps seem to require between 64 and 512 MB of permgen to work properly. In order to find your limits, experiment a bit.

to solve this issue you have change your VM arguments

```
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

add above two line in VM argument  i am sure you will not face this problem any more

to know more about go to [OutOfMemory](https://plumbr.eu/outofmemoryerror/permgen-space)

Answer (score 1):

Low memory configuration :-

It is possible that you have estimate less memory for your application for example your application need 2 Gb of memory but you have configured only 512 Mb so here you will get an OOME(Out-of-memory errors )

Due to Memoryleak :-

Memory leak is responsible for decreasing the available memory for heap and can lead to out of memory error for more read What is a Memory Leak in java?

Memory fragmentation :-

It is possible that there may be space in heap but it may be not contiguous . And heap  needs  compaction . Rearrange its memory.

Excess GC overhead :-

Some JVM implementations, such as the Oracle HotSpot, will throw an out-of-memory error when GC overhead becomes too great. This feature is designed to prevent near-constant garbage collection—for example, spending more than 90% of execution time on garbage collection while freeing less than 2% of memory. Configuring a larger heap is most likely to fix this issue, but if not you’ll need to analyze memory usage using a heap dump

Allocating over-sized temporary objects:-

Program logic that attempts to allocate overly large temporary objects. Since the JVM can’t satisfy the request, an out-of-memory error is triggered and the transaction will be aborted. This can be difficult to diagnose, as no heap dump or allocation-analysis tool will highlight the problem. You can only identify the area of code triggering the error, and once discovered, fix or remove the cause of the problem.

for more pls visit my site

http://all-about-java-and-weblogic-server.blogspot.com/2014/02/main-causes-of-out-of-memory-errors-in.html