# How to read an image from stream?

Tags: java, image, stream, png

One may suggest that `BufferedImage` is the best option to process an image in Java. While it's convenient, when reading huge images it often ends up in:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Increasing VM size isn't a solution since some input files are really huge in my case.

So I'm looking for the way(s) how an image can be read progressively, from a stream.

I suspect that `ImageIO.createImageInputStream()` from the `ImageIO` might fit the bill, but I'm not sure how to use it to read the [chunks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#Technical_details) progressively. 
Also, there are the classes `PNGMetadata` & `PNGImageReader` available on the JDK's `rt.jar` which seem to be useful, but I didn't find simple examples of their usage.

Is this the way to go, or there are better alternatives?

Comment: Please care to leave a comment if u downvote or cast a vote to close.

Comment: No need, the tooltip for the downvote arrow already tells you everything you need to know

Comment: @Clive : thanks for the tip. However if I was able to know how to access header using java, I wouldn't have post it. For clarity I can edit the question. Finally I can't accept that it's `not useful` since SO has too many `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` when using `BufferedImage` kind of questions.

Comment: I'm not passing judgement, just stating a fact. The last line of your question (which admittedly wasn't the last line before I edited it) will surely attract downvotes all day long based on the tooltip I mentioned

Comment: Thanks for your edit @Clive , I'll rearrange things a bit. But frankly my research was so unfruitful that I have nothing to show. If this post receives solution, it will benefit all those people suffering from the `heap space` issue.

Comment: @Clive : I've updated the question - have a look now. It should fit the standards I guess.

Comment: Looks good to me, voted to re-open

Comment: In case this doesn't get reopened: see [PNGJ](http://pngj.googlecode.com/)

Comment: Seems promising @leonbloy. I wanna get it reopened though & thanks for the edit.

Comment: What do you want to do with the images? Display them? Then they will also consume memory at some point. Process them somehow? If so, how? And what environment are you on? I can easily read and an display an almost 100 MB PNG (panorama) in my desktop JVM with default memory settings. I had do manually decrease memory, e.g. via `-Xmx64M` in oder to provoke an `OutOfMemoryError`. I think what you want to do determines the solution.

Comment: @kriegaex : at basic level I will go with `point processing`(1x1 filters). Later on will apply larger filters, which wont be an easy task on 1D array. There is no problem with displaying, I've workarounds. My JVM hardly supports 100MB images, where the actual sizes ~GB.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510188/what-is-an-outofmemoryerror-and-how-do-i-debug-and-fix-it.

Comment: I had a quick look at it @Raedwald, seems generic, but I'm particularly interested in images.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Java APIs for reading and manipulating images aren't really stream-based in the way you seem to think. The `ImageInputStream` is just a convenience wrapper that allows reading `byte`s and other primitive types from different inputs (`RandomAccessFile`s, `InputStream`s etc).

I've been thinking about creating an API for reading "pixel streams", to allow chaining of processing filters without using much memory. But the need has never been serious enough to be worth the effort. Feel free to hire me, if you like to hear more ideas or have a working implementation. ;-)

Still, as I see it, you have multiple options to achieve your ultimate goal, to be able to process large images:

1. Use `BufferedImage` as is, and the `ImageIO` API to read an image in smaller parts to conserve memory. This will be quite efficient for some formats, less efficient for other formats, due to the implementation (i.e. the default `JPEGImageReader` will read the entire image in native memory before handing smaller region over to the Java heap, but the `PNGImageReader` might be okay).

   Something along the lines of:

   ```
   ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
   ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next(); // TODO: Test hasNext()
   reader.setInput(stream);

   int width = reader.getWidth(0);
   int height = reader.getHeight(0);

   ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();

   for (int y = 0; y < height; y += 100) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x += 100) {
             param.setSourceRegion(new Rectangle(x, y, 100, 100)); // TODO: Bounds check

             // Read a 100 x 100 tile from the image
             BufferedImage region = reader.read(0, param);

             // ...process region as needed...
        }
   }
   ```
2. Read the entire image at once, into an memory mapped buffer. Feel free to try some [experimental classes](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/sandbox/sandbox-common/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/MappedImageFactory.java) I've made for this purpose (using `nio`). Reading will be slower than reading to a pure memory image, and processing will also be slower. But if you are doing computations on smaller regions of the image at a time, it could be about as fast as in-memory with some optimizations. I've read > 1 GB images into a 32 MB JVM using these classes (real memory consumption is of course far greater).

   Again, here's an example:

   ```
   ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(input);
   ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(stream).next(); // TODO: Test hasNext()
   reader.setInput(stream);

   int width = reader.getWidth(0);
   int height = reader.getHeight(0);
   ImageTypeSpecifier spec = reader.getImageTypes(0).next(); // TODO: Test hasNext(); 

   BufferedImage image = MappedImageFactory.createCompatibleMappedImage(width, height, spec)

   ImageReadParam param = reader.getDefaultReadParam();
   param.setDestination(image);

   image = reader.read(0, param); // Will return same image as created above

   // ...process image as needed...
   ```
3. Some formats, like uncompressed TIFF, BMP, PPM etc, keeps the pixels in the file in a way that it would be possible to memory-map them directly to manipulate them. Requires some work, but should be possible. TIFF also supports tiles that might be of help. I'll leave this option as an exercise, feel free to use the classes I linked above as a starting point or inspiration. ;-)
4. JAI may have something that can help you. I'm not a big fan, due to it's many unresolved bugs and lack of love and development by Oracle. But worth checking out. I *think* they have support for tileable  and disk-based `RenderedImage`s as well. Again, I'll leave this option for you to explore further.

Comment: Seems manageable, I actually was nowhere prior to both of the answers. Lets see how far I can go with my `(inspi|explo)ration`. Will definitely seek support from you fellas. By the way +1 for the hiring offer, although I'm just a

Answer (score 5):

The memory problem is surely related not with the decoding process itself but with storing the full image in memory as a `BufferedImage`. It is possible to read a PNG image progressively, but:

- This is only marginally related to the organization in "chunks", more so with the fact that PNG files are encoded line-by-line, and so they can be -in principle- read line-by-line.
- The above assumption breaks in the case of interlaced PNGs - but one should not expect to have huge PNG images stored in interlaced format
- While some PNG libraries allow for progressive (line-by-line) decoding (eg: [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/book/chapter14.html)), the standard Java API does not give you that.

I was faced with that problem and I ended up coding my own Java library: [PNGJ](https://code.google.com/p/pngj/). It's quite mature, it allows reading PNG images line by line, minimizing memory consumption, and write them in the same way (Even interlaced PNGs can be read, but in this case the memory problem will not go away.) 
If you only need to do some "local" image processing (modify each pixel value depending on the current value and the neighbours, and write it back) this should help.