# Out of Memory Error

Tags: java, file-io, out-of-memory, heap-memory, overwrite

I am trying to rewrite a file after someone's won or lost a game of blackjack. Every time I run the game and win, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(Unknown Source)
    at User.setWinnings(User.java:278)
    at Blackjack.addWinnings(Blackjack.java:182)
    at Blackjack.showWinMessage(Blackjack.java:323)
    at Blackjack.showOutcome(Blackjack.java:308)
    at Blackjack.actionPerformed(Blackjack.java:401)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is the code for the setWinnings method

```
public void setWinnings(int winnings2) {
    winnings = winnings2;

    IO.openInputFile("users.txt");
    String line = IO.readLine();
    StringBuilder newFile = new StringBuilder();

    while(line != null){
        String tokens[] = line.split("%");

        if(tokens.length > 0){

            if(tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase(this.getUserID())){
                String newLine = tokens[0] + tokens[1]+ tokens[2] + winnings2 + tokens[4]+ tokens[5]+ tokens[6];

                newFile.append(newLine);
                newFile.append("\n");
            } else {
                newFile.append(line);
                newFile.append("\n");
            }

        }
    }

    IO.closeInputFile();
    IO.createOutputFile("users.txt");
    IO.println(newFile.toString());
    IO.closeOutputFile();

}
```

I've already tried going into control panel and changing whatever that field was called under java to -Xms2048m or something. Any ideas why this won't work?

Edit: Note that the size of users.txt is only 82 bytes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an OutOfMemoryError and how do I debug and fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510188/what-is-an-outofmemoryerror-and-how-do-i-debug-and-fix-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a loop

```
while(line != null) { 
    ...
}
```

But within the loop you never read another line. The loop never terminates and you keep appending the same data to `newFile`.  Eventually you consume all of memory.

Comment: Brb kms... What a dumb mistake. I'll try adding in a new readline statement

Answer (score 0):

You assign value to the `line` variable only once, at a declaration stage: `String line = IO.readLine();` and sin'ceit happens before the `while` loop, inside the loop you allways use the same first `line` without reassigning it with new lines from the input file.

In other words, the `while` loop runs infinitely, or until the memory runs out, as happened in your case.

You have to add `line = IO.readLine();` just before the ending of the while loop scope.