# wso2 identity server java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I've encountered outOfMemoryError when running wso2 identity server as key manager of my wso2 api manager. I use the  wso2 identity server 5.1.0 and  wso2 api manager 1.10.0. Some logs that I got are :

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-04-01 03:40:28,196] ERROR {org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Poller} -   
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

TID: [-1234] [] [2016-04-01 04:23:05,784] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.CarbonDeploymentSchedulerTask} -  Error while running deployment scheduler..  
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

TID: [-1] [] [2016-03-30 08:57:46,404] ERROR {org.apache.directory.server.ldap.handlers.LdapRequestHandler} -  ERR_732 Cannot process a Request while binding 

TID: [-1] [] [2016-04-01 09:26:25,208]  WARN {org.apache.directory.shared.asn1.ber.Asn1Decoder} -  The PDU has been fully decoded but there are still bytes in the buffer.
```

I've tried to force kill the wso2is and started it, but sometimes after restarting, the problem appears again.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you checked the heapdump?

Comment: @ruccive, How much heap size you have allocated? We need atleast 512 MB. Check [Installation Prerequisites](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Installation+Prerequisites)

Comment: @AbimaranKugathasan : i didn't modify the default setting, so i guess -Xms 256 -Xmx 1024 (from what i read in wso2server.sh). should i raise it to higher value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an OutOfMemoryError and how do I debug and fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510188/what-is-an-outofmemoryerror-and-how-do-i-debug-and-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with -Xmx 2048 in wso2server.sh

Comment: i have change the Xmx option, and it works for now. But will the problem raise again sometimes in the future?, for example when peak load

Comment: i've changed it, and the problem is still there