# How to solve OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

I am getting this error when running this code

```
private static List<Integer> array(int num) {
       List<Integer> value = new ArrayList<>();

        while (num != 1) {
            if(num % 2 == 0) {
             value.add(num + 2);
             }else {
              value.add(num * 3 + 1);
             }
        }
       System.out.println(value);
        return value;
    }
```

Can i get an explanation of whats wrong ?

Comment: You never modify `num`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an OutOfMemoryError and how do I debug and fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510188/what-is-an-outofmemoryerror-and-how-do-i-debug-and-fix-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an infinite loop. Each iteration will add to the List until you run OutOfMemory. You need to change *num* during the loop in such a way that it becomes *1* at some point so the loop ends.

Answer (score 2):

Your while condition never equates to false, so the loop runs endlessly. As shmosie said, you never modify `num`, so maybe look into modding num, or performing some operation on it so that it actually equals 1 in order for your loop to stop